# Java authentication

Tags: java, user-interface

I need to read the text which user will enter in boxes and process for changing the account. How do we do that?

```
public void changePassword() {
    String ppaswd;
    String confir;
    String antigua;
    change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ppaswd = txt3.getText();
            confir = txt2.getText();
            antigua = txt1.getText();

        }

    });
    if (antigua.equals(nueva)) {
        if (ppaswd.equals(confir)) {
            nueva2 = confir;
            System.out.println(nueva2);
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters mind how you ask question... The way you have written it... Some users might find it rude...

Comment: Your question is missing a question.

Comment: but it´is posible? i don´t want that you do it only i wanna know how i can get the text user writte on JTextField to the String

Comment: @CoderNeji nueva is confir. I know, it makes no sense.

Comment: "nueva" is the public string var of the class

Comment: @unOA What is possible? Getting the text? You already did that.

Comment: but only localy to the metod i wanna save it

Comment: @unOA get it returned from the method to the place where you called the method and then save it.

Comment: I think OP means he has the logic function written there, but he needs to connect it with the UI textboxes

Comment: yes, how i can get this text from boxe to one string variable

Answer (score 1):

The context this method is in is hard to understand but I will try to point you in the right way:

I assume that there are three text boxes where the user enters some data and you wish to validate and invoke other actions on that data later on.

The program flow would typically be:

1. You attach a Listener to your button
2. A User presses a button, e.g.
3. The Listener that is attached to the button is invoked when the button is clicked
4. The Listener can now gather the data from the text boxes and pass them to another method you define where you can handle validation and other actions

So in order to solve your problem:

```
// this is called once
void initButton() {
  change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      String ppaswd = txt3.getText();
      String confir = txt2.getText();
      String antigua = txt1.getText();
      changePassword(ppaswd, confir, antigua);
    }
}

// this is called everytime your ActionListener is called on an event
void changePassword(String ppaswd, String confir, String antigua) {
  if (antigua.equals(nueva)) {
    if (ppaswd.equals(confir)) {
      nueva2 = confir;
      System.out.println(nueva2);

      // I would not suggest to do that here...but for now I hope it's okay
      <frame of the pwd form>.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it works bur the problem is the same when i call it from the other class

Comment: `public void changePassword() {
  change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Change ch = new Change(pas);
    ch.setVisible(true);
    pas = ch.nuevas();
    System.out.println(ch.nuevas());

   }
  });

 }`

Comment: Well, it is still really hard to understand everything related to your snippet.
Could you edit your initial Question with more information, the whole class and everything related to it would be a great starting point.